# replace multiple values+in SQL query?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, string

I want to do **search**ing for data using users' entry in a field. That is if user enters **"D+t+y+g,k,j,h"** want to search for values having letters **"d and t and y and g or k or j or h"**.  I tried the PHP `str_replace` function, but didn't like the result.

```
//kw is text field... 
if($kw != "") {
  //here we check for some data in field; if yes, continue below

  //c is for ',' replaced in JavaScript 
  $kw1 = str_replace("c"," OR bcm.keywords LIKE '$kw%' ",$kw);

  //p is for '+' replaced in JavaScript//'bcm' is table name.
  $kw3 = str_replace("p"," AND bcm.keywords LIKE '$kw%' ",$kw1);

  //for appending into main query string
  $app.=$kw3; 
  //$app.=" AND bcm.keywords LIKE '$kw%'";
}
```

...but for the input **"D+t+y+g,k,j,h"** the query is coming out like this:

```
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' t 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' y 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' g 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'D 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' t 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' y 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' gckcjch%' k 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'D 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' t 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' y 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' gckcjch%' j 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'D 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' t 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' y 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'Dptpypgckcjch%' gckcjch%' h**
```

...when what I want/need is:

```
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'D%' 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 't%' 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'y%' 
AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'g%' 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'k%' 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'j%' 
OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'h%'
```

Comment: You know ... its too hard to read your code, and your question. I'm closing as `not a real question`...

Comment: @Chacha: If you can vote to close, then you should also have access to edit the post to clean up the formatting.  There's even a badge for it - Strunk & White - after you update 300 posts.

Comment: They will never learn if someone else fixes it for them ;)

Comment: @Jani: Not if you don't provide a link to the markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Ponies Yes, I know. I didn't understand the question, and was going to go edit it, but it turned out to be a big mess on the inside of the post as well. I've been around for awhile, so yes, I do know the abilities/badges/what not. :)

Comment: @dev646: What database?  Probably no less complex, but might be a better idea to convert the filter criteria to a regex.

Comment: sorry guys ... but i gave enough formatting for the code portion alone... the portion you've sectioned now is the Sql Query part... !
That's y ... anyways sorry again... and thanx for all the prompt response... it was getting heated up here in my office  !
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in javascript

```
var getSearchSql = function(kw) 
{
  if(kw != "") 
  {
    var ors = kw.split(",");
    var sql = "";
    var sqlVariable = "bcm.keywords";
    for(i = 0; i < ors.length; i++)
    {
      var ands = ors[i].split("+");
      sql += (i == 0)? "(": " OR (";
      for(j = 0; j < ands.length; j++)
      {
          sql += (j == 0)? "": " AND ";
          sql += sqlVariable + " LIKE '%" + ands[j] + "%' "
      }
      sql += ")"
    }
  }
  return sql;
}
```

yields the following (when `kw = "D+t+y+g,k,j,h"`)

```
(bcm.keywords LIKE '%D%' 
    AND bcm.keywords LIKE '%t%' 
    AND bcm.keywords LIKE '%y%' 
    AND bcm.keywords LIKE '%g%') 
OR (bcm.keywords LIKE '%k%') 
OR (bcm.keywords LIKE '%j%') 
OR (bcm.keywords LIKE '%h%')
```

Comment: beauty... thnx ... i went through this way but couldn't continue ... nice work !

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?
    $str = "D+t+y+g,k,j,h";

    $comNext = 0;
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < strlen($str);$i++){
        if ($str[$i+1] == "+"){
            $andKey .= " AND bcm.keywords LIKE '".$str[$i]."%'";
        }else if ($str[$i+1] == "," || $str[$i+1] == ""){
            if ($comNext == 0)
                $andKey .= " AND bcm.keywords LIKE '".$str[$i]."%'";
            else
                $orKey .= " OR bcm.keywords LIKE '".$str[$i]."%'";
            $comNext = 1;
        }

    }
    echo $andKey.$orKey;
?>
```

Gives Me:

> AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'D%' AND
>   bcm.keywords LIKE 't%' AND
>   bcm.keywords LIKE 'y%' AND
>   bcm.keywords LIKE 'g%' OR bcm.keywords
>   LIKE 'k%' OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'j%' OR
>   bcm.keywords LIKE 'h%'

Comment: very well done...!
instead of '+ and ,' if we give 'p and c' it's taking this too and shows output including...
'AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'l%' AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'p%' AND bcm.keywords LIKE 'o%'  OR bcm.keywords LIKE 'c%'

Comment: meaning instead of using + and , as delimeters. you want, p and c as delimeters.. it cant be done, coz letters are the key in searching

Comment: xactly... but this is a new idea for me.. beauty !

Answer (score 0):

**The answer below with comments for someone's reference... Thanx for the help dear ones...**

```
var ors = kw.split(",");//SPLITS WHERE , IS PRESENT
var sql = "";//INITIALISE SQL VARIABLE,TO BE PASSED TO AJAX
var sqlVariable = " LOWER(bcm.keywords)";//CONVERTS TO LOWER CASE FOR CHECKING, FROM DB
for(i = 0; i < ors.length; i++)// INITIALISE ARRAY TO GIVE OR WHERE , IS PRESENT 
                               // AND FOR FURTHER SPLITTING WHERE + IS PRESENT TILL ORS LENGTH ... 
                               // IE: ORS. LENGTH WILL HAVE VALUE FOR AT LEAST SINGLE , IN STRING
{
  var ands = ors[i].split("+");//SPLIT STRING WHERE + IS PRESENT
  sql += (i == 0)? "(": " OR (";//REPLACE , WITH OR
  for(j = 0; j < ands.length; j++)// SIMILAR STEPS TO ABOVE TO REPLACE + WITH AND
  {
      sql += (j == 0)? "": " AND ";
      sql += sqlVariable + " LIKE '%" + ands[j] + "%' "

  }
  sql += ")"// THE FINAL SQL ,WITH ALL BRACKETS, IS PASSED TO AJAX FOR 
               APPENDING TO SOME QUERY STATEMENT.
}
```

**:)**

Comment: Maybe it's better to put this comments directly in @ecounysis answer (SO is a collaborative place) or to add your chunk of commented code at the end of his answer. (better if lower case) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript to write SQL statements is insane IMHO, you're opening a wide security breach in you application !

You'd better use json or any other format if you want to treat data client-side before submiting them, but please, leave SQL for server-side processing.